# Append python dictionary to json by key

Tags: python, json

using Python3 I would like to append to an existing json file, with the following format

```
[{
  "employee_name": "John Doe",
  "employee_id": "1234",
  "20200401": {
    "clocked-in": "05:55:22",
    "clocked-out": "15:02:22"
  }
},
{
  "employee_name": "Ryan Jackson",
  "employee_id": "4444",
  "20200401": {
    "clocked-in": "05:45:10",
    "clocked-out": "14:50:18"
  }
}]
```

this new data for John Doe -- either by searching/matching by [employee_name] field or [employee_id] field..

```
  "20200402": {
      "clocked-in": "05:50:18",
      "clocked-out": "14:30:22"
  }
```

The result would look something like

```
[{
  "employee_name": "John Doe",
  "employee_id": "1234",
  "20200401": {
    "clocked-in": "05:55:22",
    "clocked-out": "15:02:22"
  },
  "20200402": {
    "clocked-in": "05:50:18",
    "clocked-out": "14:30:22"
  }
},
{
  "employee_name": "Ryan Jackson",
  "employee_id": "4444",
  "20200401": {
    "clocked-in": "05:45:10",
    "clocked-out": "14:50:18"
  }
}]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dict.update() method to achieve the above,

```
# python3
import json

with open('test.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

new_dict = dict()
new_dict["YYYYMMDD"] = {
    "key2": "val2",
    "key1": "val1"
}

data.update(new_dict)

with open('test.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```